# ERPConnect SAP Table Join and filter (Query) without creating a SAP Query

Tags: abap, saprfc, opensql, sap-erp, erpconnect

I know very little about SAP and I have been asked to extract some data from it using ERPConnect (and if required LINQ to SAP)

I can see that it is possible to create BAPIs and Queries in SAP but these need to be pre-defined within SAP and then ERPConnect can be used to get data via those BAPIs and Queries.

Is it possible to use ERPConnect to create a query for me, instead of the Queries needing to exist in SAP? i.e. Join and filter several Tables and return the results?

I am also opposed to extracting data for 3 very large tables and then working out the joins and filtering it afterwards, my intention is to generate the query first and then only get what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to have someone code the selection in ABAP, wrap it in a RFC-enabled function module and use it. If for some reason this is not possible, you might want to look at `RFC_READ_TABLE` - but be aware of its limitations, there are numerous questions about it here. I find it hard to give more detailed recommendations based on the rather vague question.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to see if this is at all possible Only via ERPConnect i.e. not coding any changes in SAP. Your answer makes me believe that it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know this is late, but there is an alternative.  You could develop a general-purpose remote-enabled function to which you can pass your query (including joined queries), and execute it within SAP, returning the results to the caller. ERPConnect also includes built-in query capability.  I wouldn't dismiss it without investigating further.  I've done many queries against SAP tables using ERPConnect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you know of any examples of this? I am no longer having to work on this but the information would still be very useful. Thanks